# Need Last Month of Last Year Data

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to write a query that looks at the last month and last month of last year data to compare. So since I am writing this in August of 2022 I want to see July of 2022 and July of 2021. I know I can run a between dates and have to update it every month but I want this to feed into PowerBi and be an automated report.

I can get last month's just fine the issue is last year last month. I have tried a couple of different queries and they either error out and fail or return nothing.

I am currently skipping the part for last month as I know it works. Can I please get some help with the last year part?

```
Declare @StartofCurrentMonth datetime
Set @StartofCurrentMonth = dateadd(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)

Select BranchID, ItemID, CAST(Ledgerdate AS Date) As 'LedgerDate', TransactionType

From ItemLedger

Where --LedgerDate >= DateAdd(Month, -1, @StartofCurrentMonth) AND LedgerDate < @StartofCurrentMonth OR 
**Ledgerdate >= DATEADD(Year, -1, @startofcurrentMonth) AND LedgerDate <** **DATEADD(Month,-12,@startofCurrentMonth)**

AND TransactionType IN ('Item.Move', 'Item.Putaway')
Order By LedgerDate
```

Thank you

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: "I can get last month's just fine" - then subtract a year from it....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally.

I changed the last year stuff to:

```
Ledgerdate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, @startofcurrentMonth) AND LedgerDate < DATEADD(Month,-12,@startofCurrentMonth))
```

Thank you.